# Does positivity of the n(n-1)/2 principal minors formed from 2 x 2 submatrices ensure positive-definiteness of the n x n matrix itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis, positivity

I am interested in conditions under which an $n \times n$ matrix ($\rho$) is positive definite. Of course, one necessary and sufficient set of conditions is that the $n$ leading minors of $\rho$ each be positive.

What if I require that all the $\frac{n (n-1)}{2}$ principal minors constructed by taking the determinants of the $2 \times 2$ submatrices
\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \rho _{\text{ii}} & \rho _{\text{ij}} \\
 \rho _{\text{ji}} & \rho _{\text{jj}} \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}
for $i= 1,\ldots,n-1$, $j=i+1,\ldots n$ be themselves positive?

Clearly, for the trivial $n=2$ case, positive-definiteness holds, but is this the case for all/any $n>2$?

Comment: $$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
3 & -2 & -2 \\
-2 & 3 & -2\\
-2 & -2 & 3
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks, Will Jagy! So, can such counterexamples to positive-definiteness, despite positivity of the principal 2 x 2 minors, be constructed for all n>2? I surmise so.

Comment: @PaulB.Slater - Yes. More generally, you can always find $n \times n$ matrices that are not positive definite, but all of their principal minors (other than the full $n \times n$ minor) are positive.

Comment: i think this is true: if A[1:1], A[1:2,1:2], ... , A[1:n,1:n] are PD, then A is PD.

Comment: for only 2 by 2 principals think about A+I where A is the adjacency of a matrix. Then all the principals of A+I are PSD, but I don't think if A+I will be PSD. 

For instance for regular bipartite graphs, spectrum of A is symmetric with lambda_min(A)=-k where k is any vertex degree.

Comment: okey, what if you consider 2I+A. Then every 2 by 2 principal is PD. But 2I+A is not even PSD.

Answer (score 2):

The one I put first was
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
3 & -2 & -2 \\
-2 & 3 & -2 \\
-2 & -2 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

At the cost of possible non-integer value on the main diagonal, we may take real $w> 0$  in

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
w & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & w & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & w & -1& -1 \\
-1 & -1 & -1 & w& -1 \\
-1 & -1 & -1 & -1& w \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
where we call the dimension $n.$  The eigenvalues of the matrix of all entries $-1$ are $0,0,0,.., -n \; . \; \; \; $  We have added $(w+1)I,$ so these eigenvalues are  $w+1, w+1, ...., w+1, w+1 - n. \; \; $ If $ w > n-1 $ all   eigenvalues become positive. So, to get all principal minors (other than the entire matrix) positive we may take $w > n-2; \; \;$   if $w < n-1$ the determinant of the entire matrix is negative. So, take $n-2 < w < n-1.$  If we make the off-diagonal elements $-2$  instead, we may use an integer in $w=2n-3$

There is a pattern we may use for a basis of eigenvectors,
the columns of
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1    \\
  1  &  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1    \\
  1  &  0  &  2  &  -1  &  -1    \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  3  &  -1    \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  4    \\
  \end{array}
\right),
$$
are pairwise orthogonal.